# Flowgear Google App Engine Database Connection via internate exposed

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, database-connection, flowgear

I created connection by **DropPoint** .But I will connect google app engine  database via **Internet Exposed** .I don't know how it connects.Please help me.
My error is :Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Answer (score 1):

The database just needs to be exposed to the Internet for Flowgear to connect to it without using a DropPoint. For MS SQL Server this would usually be a matter of publishing the SQL Server on TCP port 1433.

To connect to the SQL instance from Flowgear, just provide the Internet IP or domain at which the service is exposed - eg. mysqlserver.company.com. For MS SQL, you can also include the port number if you are not using a standard port like this "mysqlserver.company.com,10000" (note that this is a comma NOT a colon).

If you only want to expose SQL to Flowgear (as opposed to the entire Internet), you can expose it to only the specific IP range used by Flowgear.

If you're on a trial account, this is 41.77.56.0/24. If you're on a subscription account, you can check the range with Flowgear's support.